# Can I convolve over spatially remote pixels in 1DConv in Keras

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras

I was successfully able to use keras's Conv1D layer for sentence multi-category classification. Now I would like to use it for binary classification deciding whether a person is going to ask for a loan based on some info about people. I consider the input as a sentence [age, income, education ...] --> 'A person with age, income and education ...' so I assume I can use Conv layer to slide over words and build filters over word n-grams. Regular convolution layer tries to filter adjucent vector fields (top of the image shows convolution lengths of 2 with stride 1). Since I do not know which input variable might corelate, I would like to try filters over combinations of all words and thus do convolutions as on the bottom of the picture in case of kernel_size=2 [age-income, age-eduction, age-..., income-education, income-..., education-...]. 
[image]
Is there some fuctionality like that in Keras already? Do I have to augment the input vector and create all combinations of the input variables ? Did you try similar approach for this kind of clasification task?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have realized a work around. After I played with strides, delation and input tensor modification; in the end I used brute force and combine each of the pairs in the input using `itertools.combinations` to concatenate embedding layers for each input. This improved my prediction by 1.5 percent points over the simple dense layers model (I tested over hundred combinations of those).

Assuming you have an input pandas dataframe named `features` containing integers (label were tokenized) I create the model like this:

```
embedding_output_dim = 8

em, inputs = {}, {}
for name in features:
    vocabulary = features[name].max()+1 #for lookups max = nunique()
    inputs[name] = Input(shape=(1,))
    em[name] = Embedding(vocabulary,embedding_output_dim)(inputs[name])

conv,concatem = [], []
i = 0
for a,b in list(itertools.combinations([key for key in em], 2)):
    print(a,b,i)
    concatem.append(concatenate([em[a],em[b]],axis=1))
    conv.append(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2,  activation='relu')(concatem[i]))
    i += 1


convmerge = concatenate([con for con in conv],axis=1)
convmerge = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2,  activation='relu')(convmerge)
#possibly add further Conv1D and MaxPooling1D
flatten = Flatten()(convmerge)
d = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid')(flatten)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs[name] for name in features], outputs=d)
```

For training your model you would use original `features` dataframe.

```
batch_size = 32
history = model.fit(x = [features[name] for name in features], y = np.array(y), batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1, validation_split=.1)
```

Don't be scared by the number of parameters. In case one of your input variables have very high vocabulary size (e.g. Age goes up to 100, bude Income can go to milions (of course you can scale it down)), then embedding parameters can grow a lot, though the training might still be quite quick since training of the embedding layers is not that resource consumming.